# C# WPF Thread accessed from a thread other than the

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a WPF application that takes a video and screenshots it every second while playing.

Code

```
    public Form2(string url)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = url;

        new Thread(delegate(){
            CheckFrame();
        }).Start();

    }
    private void CheckFrame()
    {        
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Bounds.Width, axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Bounds.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
            g.CopyFromScreen(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PointToScreen(
                        new System.Drawing.Point()).X,
                    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PointToScreen(
                        new System.Drawing.Point()).Y, 0, 0, axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Bounds.Size);
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = screenshot;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

When using the x y values of the media player itself I get the error

```
Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'axWindowsMediaPlayer1' 
accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

When using 0 as X/Y values so just 0px and 0px from the form point of view,it runs fine

Comment: In WPF you should probably try to use Task (TPL) and Dispatcher objects. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use Timer:

```
Timer tm = new Timer();

public Form2(string url)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = url;

    tm.Interval = 1000;
    tm.Tick += tm_Tick;
    tm.Start();
}

int i = -1;
void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (++i < 100)
    {
        Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Bounds.Width, axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
        g.CopyFromScreen(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PointToScreen(
                    new System.Drawing.Point()).X,
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PointToScreen(
                    new System.Drawing.Point()).Y, 0, 0, axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Bounds.Size);
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = screenshot;
    }
    else
    {
        i = -1;
        tm.Stop();
    }
}
```

Note: To take screenshot with your method, `axWindowsMediaPlayer1` must visible on the screen.